# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.compat.numpy' Venv Py3.6.4, pandas 0.220

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I'm stuck with a python virtual env installation and particularly pandas.

Pip list:
    numpy (1.14.2)
    pandas (0.22.0)
    pip (9.0.1)

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar 12 2018, 17:59:42) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.compat.numpy'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have several installations of pandas (using apt and using pip)

Remove all:

```
sudo apt-get purge  python3-pandas
sudo pip3 uninstall pandas
```

Install using pip3:

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

Try the following and it should work

```
python3
>>import pandas
```